# Viewing an xml file with a different file extension as xml within Google Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome

I'm sure this should be simple, but I've got totally stuck. What I'd like to do is view CML (Chemical Markup Language) files on my harddrive within chrome. If I view an arbitrary xml file chrome displays this beautifully.

If I view a cml file on the web, this usually displays fine. However, if I try and view a cml file on my harddrive, chrome insists on downloading it. More simply:

http://www.xml-cml.org/examples/schema24/table1.cml - works
file://Users/me/table1.cml - doesn't

If I rename the file extension to xml, then it works.

I know there are umpteen extensions I could download to do this, but it seems overkill as chrome already does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

CML files get rendered as XML from the server because the server is telling Chrome it is XML with header `Content-Type:application/xml`. When a local file is opened there is no `Content-Type` header so Chrome guesses off of the file extension and in this case is not aware of CML. You could open a feature request for Chrome to read CML files as XML but I don't know if they will implement it: http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's helpful to understand why I was struggling and that I wasn't just missing something simple. I can't help thinking there must be some setting somewhere I could set to tell chrome to use the XML content handler for CML files.